# Midpoint Rule - Numerical Method in C

Tags: c

I want to calculate approximate area that remains under the curve. Actually it is not about the mathematical isue.
This code doesnt print anything.
Where is the problem?
thanks in advance

```
double midpointrule(double,double,int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
double x,y;
int z;
scanf("%lf %lf %d", &x, &y, &z);
double midpointrule(x,y,z);
}


double midpointrule(double uplimit,double lowlimit,int interval)
{
    int i;
    double func1=0, func2=0;
    double deltax = (uplimit - lowlimit)/interval;
    for(i=1; i<=interval; i++)
    {
        func1 = func1 + pow(M_E,pow(deltax,2));
        func2 = func2 + 2*pow(M_E,deltax) - 2*deltax;
    }
func1 = func1*deltax;
func2 = func2*deltax;


printf("midpoint result for func1 = %lf\n", func1);
printf("midpoint result for func2 = %lf\n", func2);
}
```

Comment: The code works fine if you clean up missing includes, returns and then input the values from stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main` function, on line 7, you need to call your function like this

`midpointrule(x,y,z);`

Instead of like this

`double midpointrule(x,y,z);`

Also, that function is not returning anything. If you don't want it to return anything, make it a `void`.